# How to make Bootstrap 5 navbar collapse when its nav items exceed the screen width?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I understand that Bootstrap 5 Navbar has a certain breakpoint where the navbar collapses based on the screen size.
But if the user has zoom size of more than 100%, the nav items to the right get disappeared. Upon increasing the zoom size further to certain level, only then the navbar collapses.
How can I make navbar collapse when the nav items exceed the screen width, irrespective of screen size?